# preg_replace ignores sometimes linebreaks?

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace `<br>` with all its surrounding whitespaces with a linebreak `\n` and two whitespaces .

Here is an example of what I tried using regex:

```
preg_replace('#\s*<br>\s*#', "\n  ", "Der\n <br>      Hund");
```

I was expecting this:

[image]

But instead, I got this:

[image]

Which shows that `<br>` was replaced by two whitespaces, but not a line-break.

If I change the regex so that it does not match the whitespaces before the `<br>` it magically works:

```
preg_replace('#<br>\s*#', "\n  ", "Der\n <br>      Hund");
```

and I get as expected:

[image]

Why is the first regex not working as expected?
I am using PHP 7.2.24.

Comment: `\s` matches line breaks. Do you mean you only want to match horizontal ones around `<br>`? `'#\h*<br>\h*#'` / `'#\h*<br\s*/?>\h*#u'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you so much. Now I get it :D. You want to post this as an aswer, or should I remove this question?

Comment: It has been answered before several times, I even had a very unpleasant feedback from other SO users when I answered a similar question, so let's close this one.